# java parsing text file and handling each line differently

Tags: java, loops, parsing

I'm trying to read integers from a text file, but I want to handle the first line differently from the rest, and take the following lines and loop some calculations. Below is my file reader, my question is about the next part, however this may provide some context.

```
public class main
{
    BufferedReader in;
    public main() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         System.out.println("please enter the name of the text file you wish you import. Choose either inputs or lotsainputs. Nothing else");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);

        System.out.println("You have loaded file: \t\t"+filename);
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String element1 =  inputFile.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        try
        {
            while ((element1 = in.readLine()) != null)
            {      
                System.out.println("Line to process:\t\t"+element1);
                myCalculations(element1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The first text file look like this:

```
200 345 
36
```

The second text file look like this:

```
200 345 
36
45
36
21
```

Here is the method called:

```
public static void myCalculations(String s)
    {
        String[] items = s.split(" ");
        int[] results = new int[100];
        String errorMessage = "that's a wrap!";
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
        {
            try {
                int stuff = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
                results[i] = stuff;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println(results);
                System.out.println(errorMessage);   
            }
        }
        int health = result[0];
        int power = result[1]; 
        int days = result[2];
        some calculations....
        returns new health and power of the car. 
        same calculations but results[3] as the time period
        returns new health and power of car
        etc....
    }
```

The method parses the integers, puts them into the results[] array.

Lets say the first two numbers of the text file are health and power of a car. Each proceeding number are days between races. Each race there is deterioration of the of the car and engine, the amount of deterioration is a factor of days in between each race.

I have used results[3][4]&[5] and hard code the deterioration and print the results and it works, but its pretty crap. How would I improve this method? I'm copy and pasting the 'calculations'. How do I take the first line, then put the following lines in a separate loop?

ideally, the number of days in the text file could vary. ie, there could be 5 races, or there could be 3 and the program will handle both cases.

Comment: Aren't you *already* reading the first line and processing the others separately?

Comment: am i? my understanding is that I have hard coded the number of lines that can be in the file. Ie, I can use 36, 45, 36, 21 by calling each element in the array. but what happens if there are 6 iterations of days?

Comment: `while ((element1 = in.readLine()) != null)` reads all lines until EOF

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println(
                "please enter the name of the text file you wish you import. Choose either inputs or lotsainputs. Nothing else");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);


        System.out.println("You have loaded file: \t\t" + filename);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String element1 = null;
        try {
            element1 = in.readLine();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        String[] firstLine = element1.split(" ");

        Arrays.stream(firstLine).forEach(fl -> {
            System.out.println("First line element: " + fl);
        });


        //Do the staff
        String otherElement = null;


        try {
            while ((otherElement = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Line to process:\t\t" + otherElement);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

result for file:

```
1 2
3
5
7
```

is

```
You have loaded file:       
First line element: 1
First line element: 2
Line to process:        3
Line to process:        5
Line to process:        7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I like the simplicity