# using output from method for the next iteration of a loop

Tags: java, loops, methods, return

Please see my previous question for further explanation on what the program is supposed to do. So you guys don't have to read back ill also add the relevant stuff here. The question will be at the bottom.

[java parsing text file and handling each line differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280453/java-parsing-text-file-and-handling-each-line-differently)

The format of the text files is as follows:

```
200 345 
36
```

and

```
200 345 
36
45
36
21
```

The first part of this program handles the input from the file. It takes the first line, parses for integers, then saves the integers in an array.

```
public class  costOfConflictTest
{

    public static void costOfConflictTest() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        System.out.println("please enter the name of the text file you wish you import. Choose either costs.txt or lotsacosts.txt Nothing else");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);

        System.out.println("You have loaded file: \t\t\t" + filename);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String element1 = null;
        try {
            element1 = in.readLine();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }

        String[] firstLine = element1.split(" ");

        Arrays.stream(firstLine).forEach(fl -> 
        {
            System.out.println("First line element: \t\t\t" + fl);
        });

        int[] results = new int[100];
        String errorMessage = "that's a wrap!";
        for (int i = 0; i < firstLine.length; i++) 
        {
            try {
                int stuff = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[i]);
                results[i] = stuff;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println(results);
            System.out.println(errorMessage);   
            }
        }
```

second part:
This part is where it gets a little tricky to read whats going on. It takes the remaining lines, parses the integers into an array aliveSoldiers. It takes the two integers on the first line and the first integer on the second line, and puts them into a method which returns a string of two integers. This string is parsed, and the output is supposed to the first two values in the aliveSoldiers array so the method can be called again.

```
        // parsing remaining days 
        String otherElement = null;

        try {
            while ((otherElement = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Line to process:\t\t\t" + otherElement);
                String[] arr = otherElement.split(" ");
                int [] things = new int [100];
                for (int k = 0; k <arr.length; k++) 
                    {
                    try {
                        int thingsResult = Integer.parseInt(arr[k]);
                        things[k] = thingsResult;
                        System.out.println("number of days: \t\t\t"+things[k]);
                        int[] aliveSoldiers = new int[100];
                        aliveSoldiers[0] = results[0];
                        aliveSoldiers[1] = results[1];
                        aliveSoldiers[2] = things[k];

                        String returnAliveSoliders = myCalculations(aliveSoldiers[0], aliveSoldiers[1], aliveSoldiers[2]);
                        System.out.println(returnAliveSoliders);

                        String[] newItems = returnAliveSoliders.split(" ");
                        int[] newResults = new int[100];
                        for (int f = 0; f < newItems.length; f++) 
                        {
                            try {
                                int newParse = Integer.parseInt(newItems[f]);
                                newResults[f] = newParse;

                            }
                            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                                System.out.println(results);
                                System.out.println(errorMessage);   
                            }
                        } 
                        aliveSoldiers[0] = newResults[0];
                        aliveSoldiers[1] = newResults[1];
                        System.out.println(aliveSoldiers[0]);
                        System.out.println(aliveSoldiers[1]);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.println(results);
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);   
                    }
                } 

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My question: I have attempted to take the output from the method, parse for integers, and then replace what would be the first two integers in the text file. For the second iteration of the loop, the three integers the method should take are the two integers given back from the first call of the method, and then the integer on the 3rd line of the text file and so forth.
The third iteration of the main while loop should take the two integers returned from the second iteration of the method, and the 4th line of the text file.

the following code replaces the values in array aliveSoldiers, but does not seem to input back into the method.

```
aliveSoldiers[0] = newResults[0];
aliveSoldiers[1] = newResults[1];
```

Comment: What do you mean input back? To what method?

Comment: back into myCalculations. I didn't add the method here because it's really long, but it returns a string with two integers, then the loop below parses those integers and its supposed to overwrite aliveSoldiers[0] and [1], then the loop will continue

Comment: But you initialize `int[] aliveSoldiers = new int[100];` every iteration. You do overwrite it and then reset it.

Comment: that's what i thought as well. However, it doesn't...